# How can I make Emacs properly indent C99 compound literals?

Tags: c, emacs, formatting, indentation, c99

I'm writing a C99 program and using compound literals quite often. However, Emacs doesn't seem to indent them properly.

For example, here's a simple function, indented by hand:

```
SDL_Point
random_point_within_rect(SDL_Rect r)
{
    return (SDL_Point) {
        .x = (r.x + (rand() % r.w)),
        .y = (r.y + (rand() % r.h)),
    };
}
```

And here is how that looks when I use `M-x indent-region`:

```
SDL_Point
random_point_within_rect(SDL_Rect r)
{
    return (SDL_Point) {
        .x = (r.x + (rand() % r.w)),
            .y = (r.y + (rand() % r.h)),
            };
}
```

My hypothesis is that Emacs doesn't recognise the braces in `(type) { ... }` as being the same sort of thing as in `type x = { ... }`, since this, which has exactly the same contents in the braces, works fine:

```
SDL_Point
random_point_within_rect(SDL_Rect r)
{
    SDL_Point p = {
        .x = (r.x + (rand() % r.w)),
        .y = (r.y + (rand() % r.h)),
    };
    return p;
}
```

Is there a way I can get Emacs to treat compound literals like struct literals, or some other way to fix the indentation here?

Thanks.

Comment: looks like your hypothesis is right, if you eval `(setq-local c-echo-syntactic-information-p t)` you can see the indentation rules

Answer (score 0):

I filed a bug report for that exact problem; I believe emacs is treating your list as a series of statements, and commas as comma operators.

You can circumvent the problem by putting ; at the end of your lines. You can also use unnamed struct initializers, i.e.

```
return (SDL_Point){r.x + rand()%r.w, r.y + rand()%r.h}
```